# How to save the password in the hippo repository

Tags: hippocms

How to save the password in the Hippo repository?

I wrote a class which generate a new password, and i want his to be saved in the repository. But how i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cms has a plugin for changing the password via the ui. You could take a look at that for inspiration. See [org.hippoecm.frontend.plugins.cms.admin.users.User.savePassword(String)](http://svn.onehippo.org/repos/hippo/hippo-cms7/cms/trunk/perspectives/src/main/java/org/hippoecm/frontend/plugins/cms/admin/users/User.java) for an example.

Perhaps this page can help some as well:
http://www.onehippo.org/7_8/library/administration/users.html

Essentially it is a property on a node. So if you can get the node you can change it.

Comment: In groups Niels added this comment:
See org.hippoecm.frontend.plugins.cms.admin.users.User.savePassword(String)
 [1] for an example.

 HTH,
 Niels

 [1] https://svn.onehippo.org/repos/hippo/hippo-cms7/cms/trunk/perspectives/src/main/java/org/hippoecm/frontend/plugins/cms/admin/users/User.java